# How to ngIf in angular 17 with async pipe as a variable

Tags: angular

I have this in Angular 16

```
<div *ngIf="post$ | async as post">
  <h1>{{ post.attributes.title }}</h1>
</div>
```

Type of `post$` is  `Observable<ContentFile<BlogPost | Record<string, never>>>`

I want to rewrite this with the new built-in syntax for control flow.

```
@if(post$|async as post) {

}
```

`as post` part results in

> Parser Error: Unexpected token 'as' at column 13 in [post$|async as post] in ...

How to get around this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're missing the semi colon :

```
@if(post$ | async; as post) {

}
```

Comment: interesting. the error is gone. and the post is being recognized now. Is there a documentation for this? I mean, the semi-colon would terminate the statement, right?

Comment: https://angular.dev/guide/templates/control-flow#referencing-the-conditional-expressions-result